# How to Get a Site Property From a Different Site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I know of ProjectProperty, but it only allows me to retrieve a property from the current site. Is there anything like it that will allow me, in SharePoint Designer, to retrieve a property from some other site? For example (I know this doesn't work because ProjectProperty does not have a WebURL property, but you should get the idea):

```
<SharePoint:ProjectProperty runat="server" WebURL="SomeSubsite" Property="Title"/>
```

Comment: Which version of sharepoint ? Depends on where are the site you want to retrieve, if is a subsite ok no problem, otherwise you have a cross-site scripting. Hoewever you can use javascript with Client Side Object Model on Sharepoint 2010, on version 2013 you can use also the REST service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's SP 2010 or 2013, doesn't matter. I know all of the standard mechanisms, but I wanted something to go in markup.

Comment: Javascript go to in markup.

Comment: That's obviously not what I meant.